# VB.NET: How can I Optimize my own code written by VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, optimization

How can I Optimize my own code written by VB.net? Is there any tools for it? Does Visual Studio have any one? What's your suggestion? I use VS2008 as my editor.

Thank you

Comment: By optimization, do you mean you want to reduce exection speed? And is it a desktop application, ASP.Net, or what?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of optimization.

- Readability/maintainability: e.g., ReSharper
- Execution speed: e.g., .NET profiler